# What is Cause for This while updating through Sql Data EDITOR is it Necessary to have primary key for table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

What is cause for this while updating through editor in SQL Server Management Studio. Is it necessary to have primary key for table?

simple table `tab1`

schema

```
Accid(int, not null),Bench1 (varchar(50),null),Bench2(varchar(50),null)

Accid  Bench1       Bench2
-------------------------------
  1      null       null
  1      null       null
  2      null       null
  2      null       null
  3      null       null
  4      null       null

update tab1 set Bench1='xx' where accid=1
```

works fine

```
(2 row(s) affected)
```

But While Updating Through Editor giving Error
[image]

I read some posts in that they said

This issue occurs if the following conditions are true:

- The table contains one or more columns of the text or ntext data
  type.
- The value of one of these columns contains the following characters:
      Percent sign (%)
      Underscore (_)
      Left bracket ([)
- **The table does not contain a primary key.**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925719

so here why primary key is mandatory?

```
if  YES
then how it allows updating through query?
else if(NO)
what is reason behind this?
```

[image: Schema Screen Shot]

Comment: Do you have a unique key contstraint?

Comment: In my experience it does not need a primary key, but the row has to be unique in at least 1 field.  That editor limits changes to 1 row at a time. If it cannot distinguish 1 row from the next it fails.

Comment: @roryap no. I also included schema screen

Comment: @DanielE. But I updates without error through Query Editor....

Comment: Correct, as that has no 1 row per change limit.

Comment: This never happen when I use alternative front-ends to studio.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it does not need a primary key, but the row has to be unique in at least 1 field. That editor limits changes to 1 row at a time. If it cannot distinguish 1 row from the next it fails.

The query editor has no such limitation, therefore updates any and all rows matching your `WHERE` criteria.

Comment: whether sql server Uses(creates and Exec) Queries in Background while performing any operations through editor..???